# Get only numbers from string

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to get only numbers from string.

Lest say that this is my string :

`324ghgj123`

i want to get:

```
324123
```

what i have tried:

```
MsgBox(Integer.Parse("324ghgj123"))
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim mytext As String = "123a123"
Dim myChars() As Char = mytext.ToCharArray()
For Each ch As Char In myChars
     If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
          MessageBox.Show(ch)
     End If
Next
```

or:

```
Private Shared Function Num(ByVal value As String) As Integer
    Dim returnVal As String = String.Empty
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(value, "\d+")
    For Each m As Match In collection
        returnVal += m.ToString()
    Next
    Return Convert.ToInt32(returnVal)
End Function
```

Answer (score 44):

you can use `Regex` for this

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

then on some part of your code

```
Dim x As String = "123a123&*^*&^*&^*&^   a sdsdfsdf"
MsgBox(Integer.Parse(Regex.Replace(x, "[^\d]", "")))
```

Comment: So your regex reads: replace every non-digit character with the empty string. Elegant.

Comment: Accepted answer should be this.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use the fact that a String is an Array of Chars.

```
Public Function getNumeric(value As String) As String
    Dim output As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To value.Length - 1
        If IsNumeric(value(i)) Then
            output.Append(value(i))
        End If
    Next
    Return output.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
```

will give you that number as a string. Int32.Parse(resultString) will then give you the number.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually combine some of these individual answers to create a single line solution that will either return an integer with the value 0, or an integer that is the concatenation of all of the numbers in the string. Not sure how useful that is, however -- this began as a method to create a string of numbers only....

```
    Dim TestMe = CInt(Val(New Text.StringBuilder((From ch In "123abc123".ToCharArray Where IsNumeric(ch)).ToArray).ToString))
```

Answer (score 1):

Function that returns string without digits

```
Public Function _RemoveNonDigitCharacters(S As String) As String
        Return New String(S.Where(Function(x As Char) System.Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For a linear search approach you can use this algorithm, it’s in C# but can easily be translated in vb.net, hope it helps.

```
string str = “123a123”;

for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
{
    if(int.TryParse(str[i], out nval))
        continue;
    else
        str=str.Rremove(i,i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str="something1234text456"   

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RegEx.Pattern = "[^\d+]"
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True
RegEx.Global = True
numbers=RegEx.Replace(str, "")(0)
msgbox numbers
```

Comment: For VBs its tested solution

Answer (score 0):

Dim a As String = dr("hah34gnb98").ToString()

```
        Dim reg As New Regex("[^0-9]")
        a = reg.Replace(a, "") : TextBox1.Text = a
```

Answer (score 0):

string input = "Hello 20, I am 30 and he is 40";
var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").OfType().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();