# VB-Formatting output from a database field

Tags: database, vb.net, substring

I have list down items from a database field inside a combo box. The items in the field is something like this

```
BC9876
BC7654
```

I need the output in the combo box to be numeric only. Meaning my output should be like this

```
9876
7654
```

I cannot modify the data inside the database. I am lost. Do you guys have any idea on how to do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you've put much thought into this.  What if I gave you a list of numbers and said that I wanted you to display double the value of each one? Would that stump you too?  You have a list of values, you loop through it, you process each one and you put the output into another list.  Processing can be anything, e.g. multiplying a number by 2 or removing the first two characters from a `String`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only numbers from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356018/get-only-numbers-from-string)

Comment: I would suggest to do it from the database side itself, for example you can use SQL function to extract only integers from a field within the select query itself. BTW which DB are you using ?