# How to show all numbers in this string

Tags: vb.net

I want to show only numbers from a string.

This is my input:

> "aa[12]bb[34]cc[56]dd[78]"

My code so far:

```
Dim total As String
total = TextBox1.Text
Dim istart As String
Dim iend As String
Dim first As String
Dim second As String
Dim third As String
Dim four As String
Dim icount As String
icount = Len(total)
Do While icount > 0
    istart = total.IndexOf("[")
    iend = total.IndexOf("]") '
    If iend > 0 Then
        first = total.Substring(istart + 1, iend - istart - 1)
        MessageBox.Show(first)

        second = total.Substring(iend + 1, icount - iend - 1)
        MessageBox.Show(second)

        third = second.Substring(istart + 1, iend - istart - 1)
        MessageBox.Show(third)

    Else
        icount = 0
    End If
Loop
```

I expect the output

> 12
>   34
>   56
>   78

Comment: Are your numbers always in brackets like this?

Comment: yes user always put this type of input

Comment: And you want the final numbers to be seperated with an empty space? So you would get Twelve Thirty-Four Fifty-Six Seventy-Eight ?

Comment: yes or other option is like show the number in message box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way with `Regex`:

```
Dim text As String = "aa[12]bb[34]cc[56]dd[78]"

Dim numbers As String() = _
    Regex _
        .Matches(text, "(\d+)") _
        .Cast(Of Match)() _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Value) _
        .ToArray()
```

Or if the `[` and `]` are important:

```
Dim numbers As String() = _
    Regex _
        .Matches(text, "\[(\d+)]") _
        .Cast(Of Match)() _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Groups(1).Value) _
        .ToArray()
For Each number In numbers
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```

Here's what you get:

```
12 
34 
56 
78
```

Comment: I guess it's important for the numbers to be in square brackets, so perhaps something with a slightly different regex: `String.Join(vbCrLf, Regex.Matches(s, "\[([0-9]+)]").Cast(Of Match).Select(Function(m) m.Groups(1).Value))`

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think what the author originally wanted was the output in a single string seperated by whitespaces, not by carriage return. Maybe by editing the original question, you altered his will. But you did a great job in reformatting the code and the post in general.

Comment: The original question had the numbers on separate lines - they only appeared on one line due to HTML collapsing white spaces to a single space. From the separate MessageBox.Shows, I guess the separate lines were to illustrate multiple appearances of the dialog, so perhaps I should have separated them even more. Anyway, the OP seems satisfied with what they got.

Comment: Another approach to that formatting would be to use html line break `<br>` but block quote works too. Nice catch

Answer (score 1):

I got inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356018/get-only-numbers-from-string).

```
Private Function StackOverflowTest() As String
    Dim x As String = "aa[12]bb[34]cc[56]dd[78]"        
    Dim FinalString As String = ""
    Dim NumberFound As Boolean = False
    For Each ch As Char In x.ToCharArray()
        If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
            FinalString += ch
            NumberFound = True
        Else
            If NumberFound Then FinalString += " "
            NumberFound = False
        End If
    Next

    FinalString = FinalString.Remove(FinalString.Length - 1, 1)
    MsgBox(FinalString)

    Return FinalString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A non linq way. Not sure if he wanted the result in a string or an array. This produces a string.

```
Dim SourceString As String = "aa[12]bb[34]cc[56]dd[78]"
Dim FinalString As String = String.Empty
Dim Chars() = SourceString.Split("["c)
Dim SecondString = Join(Chars)
Dim NextChars() = SecondString.Split("]"c)
For Each Str As String In NextChars
    FinalString &= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Str, "[^\d]", "") & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: What's the `Join` there?

Comment: @Enigmativity It looks like the [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.join?view=netframework-4.8) where the optional second parameter (the joining string) defaults to a space.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I didnt see your comment in my inbox. Andrew is correct. In this case it is just joining all of the elements of `Chars()` back into a string to be split again into elements `NextChars()` which then all the non alpha chars are removed in the `For Each...`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim numbers As String() = _
    Regex _
        .Matches(text, "\[(\d+)]") _
        .Cast(Of Match)() _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Groups(1).Value) _
        .ToArray()
For Each number In numbers
    Console.WriteLine(number)
Next
```